# RegExp: How to remove leading and trailing groups if present from a string

Tags: regex

I am executing a regular expression against a long string, capturing portions of it.
One of this portion is between quotes and it can have any number of subportions delimited by slash, such as:

```
'george'
'paul/john'
'john/peter/charles'
...
```

the subportions are unknown and can be in any order.

I need to retrieve the string between the quotes, but also I would like to be able to remove unwanted leading and trailing groups while executing it.

For example, **if the string starts with bruce or bongo**, I want to remove it

```
'bruce/peter/marc'      -> peter/marc
'bongo/bob/kevin/chris' -> bob/kevin/chris
```

However if the strings starts with anything else, then I want to keep it

```
'alfie/george/paul'         -> alfie/george/paul
```

Only one word in the group can be present at at time, in the example above only bruce or bongo can be present at the beginning.

To do it I successfully used the following regular expression:

```
/'(?:bruce|bongo|)\/?([^']+)'/
```

In a similar way I want to remove a trailing group.
Let' say that **if the string ends with sam or mark** I want to remove this portion as well, for example:

```
'emily/grace/poppy/sam' -> emily/grace/poppy
'connor/barnaby/mark' -> connor/barnaby
```

Again, only one word of the group can be present at the end, in the example only sam or mark can end the string.

I thought to use the same as above and going with something similar to:

```
/'(?:bruce|bongo|)\/?([^']+)(?:sam|mark|)'/
```

But it's not working: bruce or bongo are removed if present, while sam or mark are always kept if present.

I know I can extract the match as it is and remove it with string manipulation methods. I am using javascript at the moment, and I can use:

```
"bruce/john/charles/sam".replace(/^(?:bruce|bongo)\//, '').replace(/\/(?:sam|mark)$/, '');
```

But I was wondering if there's a way to achieve the same result using directly the initial regular expression I execute against the long original string.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use lookarounds. You need to include the prefix and suffix in the match, so that you can replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make the middle part lazy, by adding a `?` after the `+`:

```
'(?:bruce|bongo|)\/?([^']+?)(?:sam|mark|)'
```

And if you want the capture group to exclude the `/` that occurs before `sam` or `mark`, then:

```
'(?:bruce|bongo|)\/?([^']+?)(?:\/sam|\/mark|)'
```